# How to protect the app against code injection which bypasses SSL pinning?

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, alamofire, moya

While applying an iOS app developed by me to FUT. They were able to intercept, view and modify all traffic between the app and the server even though the traffic was sent over SSL.

A selfsigned certificate was installed on the phone prior to testing. The app traffic was then redirected to a proxy server which presents the self-signed certificate.

In order to bypass the SSL Pinning, the team has hooked on the runtime of the application (process) and have injected code on runtime, which has disabled the function which checks for the SSL Pinning to be made with the corresponding server.

In case this help. I am using *Alamofire 4.7.2*, *Moya 11.0.2*

I have no idea about how to do the ssl pinning, please help.

Comment: You say you don't know how to do the ssl pinning but also that the pinning was bypassed via code injection at runtime. Can you please clarify which it is and supply  some of your code?

Comment: The title is a little misleading. Perhaps it should be changed to something like _How to protect the app against code injection which bypasses SSL pinning_

Comment: @mag_zbc you're right, sorry for that, I edited the title :D

Comment: This is not a solvable problem. They modified your binary to do something you didn't expect. You can't stop that. You an employ obfuscation and hardening to try to slow it down somewhat, but it is not solvable. (If it were solvable, then Apple would just use that technique to prevent jailbreaking. If they can't prevent jailbreaking with complete control over the entire hardware/software stack, what do you think you're going to do in a user-space sandboxed app?) There are commercial products that promise to help; I'm sure they can help somewhat against some attacks.

Comment: The more important question is "so what?" This allows someone to access the data on their own device. That is not solvable, but it also isn't by itself a problem. Unauthorized clients can contact your server and send any data they want. That's not fixable, and your server security must be robust in the presence of malicious clients. (By "so what," I'm not saying that there are no cases where this is a major problem; I'm saying it's not fixable, so you need to design to make it as small a problem as possible.)